# Using Markdown-to-JSX package to convert markup to HTML inside a React component's render function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown, markup

I am pulling JSON data from an API. The JSON contains blog posts from social media site Steemit.com. The posts are in markup and I want to grab the markup from the API, convert it to regular HTML, and display it in a React component.

Here is my render function. The API data is called in `componentDidMount` and consists of deeply nested objects. Excuse the messiness.

```
render() {
    const posts = Object.keys(this.state.myPosts);

    let page = posts.map((post, i) => {
      return (
        this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["category"] === "utopian-io"
        ?
          <div className="content-container">
            <p>
              <strong>Author: {this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["author"]}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Title: {this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["title"]}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Payout: {this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["total_payout_value"]}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>{this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["created"]}</p>
            <p><span>Category: </span>{this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["category"]}</p>

            // Successfully renders the markup, but I want to convert this to HTML so it displays as HTML
            <p>{this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["body"]}</p>

            // I have tried the following but I get a "not a string" console.error or the browser just crashes
            <Markdown>{this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["body"]}</Markdown>



          </div>
        :
        null

      );
    });

    return (
        <div>
          {page}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The Markdown-to-JSX package is successfully imported and calling it with the `<Markdown></Markdown>` tags is the appropriate way to use it. The problem is it expects a string and when I pass it `this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["body"]` it won't work. I have tried to convert the data to a string using `toString(`) and `JSON.stringify()` but I am unable to figure this out.

How do I pass the JSON markup data from the API to Markdown-to-JSX as a string?

In order words, I think converting `this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["body"]` to a string should fix this but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

If you would like to inject the HTML in the body of the post, use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.myPosts[posts[i]]["body"]}></div>
    );
}
```

You need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML because React escapes the HTML to prevent XSS ( a security stuff to avoid injecting malicious code )

- If you transform the post body to string directly, you will add in the body a lot of html tags as string, not recommended either.
- If you parse the markup, and would like to convert it, its a heavy task.
- In general, the practice for this is that the API call wouldn't return you a formatted markup.

**Option 2: npm-library**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react

You shouldn't loose the magic of React. So this probably is a nice option to convert your post patterns into React 'Post Body' Components.

Your result should be having all inside components. In this way you are keeping the benefits of React

Comment: So there's no easy way to get markup from JSON and display it?

Comment: @NickKinlen check the update. Added you another option, its a nice parser for what seems better in your case.